# RichTextEditor not working for multiple fields in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tinymce

I want to create a form like below image in mvc 5

[image]

You'll see It has two Rich Edit Text field for English and for Arabic , I followed [this Tutorial](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2657/implementing-richtexteditor-or-wysiwyg-tinymce-in-aspnet-mvc) to add those rich text fields.

but When I put that Its like below image, one of rich text field not working

[image]

this is relevant code snippet in view page

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductAbstractEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductAbstractEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductAbstractEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductAbstractAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductAbstractAr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductAbstractAr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This is model class code snippet for those fields

```
    [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed"), AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "English")]
    public string ProductAbstractEn { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed"), AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Arabic")]
    public string ProductAbstractAr { get; set; }
```

Could you please mention how can I make these two fields workable

**Edited Code**  tinymce_full_compressed.cshtml

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){tinyMCE.init({mode:"exact",elements:"@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",theme:"advanced",height:"500",width:"790",verify_html:false,plugins:"pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",theme_advanced_buttons1:"save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",theme_advanced_buttons2:"cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",theme_advanced_buttons3:"tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",theme_advanced_buttons4:"insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top",theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"left",theme_advanced_statusbar_location:"bottom",theme_advanced_resizing:false,content_css:"@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce.3.4.5/css/content.css")",convert_urls:false,template_external_list_url:"lists/template_list.js",external_link_list_url:"lists/link_list.js",external_image_list_url:"lists/image_list.js",media_external_list_url:"lists/media_list.js",})})();
</script>

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

Comment: Show the script where you attach the plug in to the textarea elements

Comment: And also show your partial for `tinymce_full_compressed.cshtml`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the code

Comment: Your problem is that your have scripts in your partials - a partial should never have scripts (your loading multiple copies it an one can wipe out the other). Attach your plugins in the main script

Comment: do I need add above script in "Add new Product" view page ?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the NuGet package from your tutorial and here is what I came up with.

In your templates (`tinymce_full_compressed`, `tinymce_full`) you have the string:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's where your component scripts are located. Because you use this template for 2 properties, you basicaly add 2 script links in your `View` and that is what causes the problem.

When I use this component, I solve this problem like this:

Delete `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` string from your templates.

In your templates change this code.

```
(function(){ 

    tinyMCE.init({

        // General options
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",
        ... //here more optins, don't touch them
    });

})();
```

To this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //To make sure that DOM is loaded
    $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)').tinymce({ //changed selector for initialization

                mode: "exact",
                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")', //this line should fix your problem in script adding
            ... //here more optins, don't touch them
        }); 
})();
```

Comment: thnks lot, I did your changes in "tinymce_full_compressed.cshtml" but then its both are not working

Comment: @Chathz what's your browser in F12 mode wrote? Any errors?

Comment: I new to this firebug console , how do I recognize any error with F12, seems like I don't have any major error

Comment: @Chathz i using chrome not firefox, in chrome there is `Console` tab where all script errors located. If you don't have any errors could be that selector, that add your plugin to `input` wrong, are you sure that you change all like i write in this case?

Comment: @yeah now my 'tinymce_full_compressed.cshtml' like exactly this http://jsfiddle.net/kanthake/nox440ch/ but I didn't change "tinymce_full.cshtml"

Comment: yeah Im not getting any major error , but I dont know catch script or css errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87358/discussion-between-teo-van-kot-and-chathz).